# How to import existing VPC in aws cdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk

Hi I am working on aws cdk. I am trying to get existing non-default vpc. I tried below options.

```
vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, id = "VPC", vpc_id='vpcid', vpc_name='vpc-dev')
```

This results in below error

```
[Error at /LocationCdkStack-cdkstack] Request has expired.
[Warning at /LocationCdkStack-cdkstack/TaskDef/mw-service] Proper policies need to be attached before pulling from ECR repository, or use 'fromEcrRepository'.
Found errors
```

Other method I tried is

```
vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_vpc_attributes(self, 'VPC', vpc_id='vpc-839227e7', availability_zones=['ap-southeast-2a','ap-southeast-2b','ap-southeast-2c'])
```

This results in

```
[Error at /LocationCdkStack-cdkstack] Request has expired.
[Warning at /LocationCdkStack-cdkstack/TaskDef/mw-service] Proper policies need to be attached before pulling from ECR repository, or use 'fromEcrRepository'.
Found errors
```

Other method I tried is

`vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, id = "VPC", is_default=True)` // This will get default vpc and this will work

Can someone help me to get non-default vpc in aws cdk? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Take a look at [aws_cdk.aws_ec2 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2.README.html#importing-an-existing-vpc) and at [CDK Runtime Context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/context.html).

> If your VPC is created outside your CDK app, you can use
> Vpc.fromLookup(). The CDK CLI will search for the specified VPC in the
> the stack’s **region and account**, and import the subnet configuration.
> Looking up can be done by VPC ID, but more flexibly by searching for a
> specific tag on the VPC.

**Usage:**

```py
# Example automatically generated. See https://github.com/aws/jsii/issues/826
from aws_cdk.core import App, Stack, Environment
from aws_cdk import aws_ec2 as ec2

# Information from environment is used to get context information
# so it has to be defined for the stack
stack = MyStack(
    app, "MyStack", env=Environment(account="account_id", region="region")
)

# Retrieve VPC information
vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(stack, "VPC",
    # This imports the default VPC but you can also
    # specify a 'vpcName' or 'tags'.
    is_default=True
)
```

**Update with a relevant example:**

```py
vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(stack, "VPC",
    vpc_id = VPC_ID
)
```

**Update with typescript example:**

```js
import ec2 = require('@aws-cdk/aws-ec2');
const getExistingVpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'ImportVPC',{isDefault: true});
```

[More info here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/VpcLookupOptions.html)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. VPC is created outside of cdk app and this is non-default vpc. from_lookup is used to get default vpc right?

Comment: Then just change `is_default` to False and provide the `vpcName`

Comment: vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, id = "VPC", vpc_name='vpc-dev' , is_default=False) this dint worked out for me. Yes my cdk is in python

Comment: Maybe this could be helpfull https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.Vpc.html#static-from-wbr-lookupscope-id-options

Comment: To make it work the environment needs to be properly defined for the stack with mandatory information `account` and `region`.

Comment: @Romain Share an example and I'll edit my answer according to it

Comment: @AmitBaranes just updated the answer with additional information. Feel free to review it. Hope it will help other people.

Comment: Please be aware that not setting isDefault is different from setting it false (or true for that matter). I can lookup my non-default VPC based on a name without errors, but the ID returned is a random one (not the right one). If I set isDefault to false, it gives me the correct one, and if I set it to true, it throws and error telling me that it is not my default VPC.

Answer (score 4):

For **AWS CDK v2** or **v1(latest)**, You can use:

```js
// You can either use vpcId OR vpcName and fetch the desired vpc
const getExistingVpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'ImportVPC',{
      vpcId: "VPC_ID",
      vpcName: "VPC_NAME"
});
```

Answer (score -1):

here is simple example

```js
//get VPC Info form AWS account, FYI we are not rebuilding we are referencing 
const DefaultVpc = Vpc.fromVpcAttributes(this, 'vpcdev', {
    vpcId:'vpc-d0e0000b0',
    availabilityZones: core.Fn.getAzs(),
    privateSubnetIds: 'subnet-00a0de00',
    publicSubnetIds: 'subnet-00a0de00'
});
    
const yourService = new lambda.Function(this, 'SomeName', {
    code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("lambda"),
    handler: 'handlers.your_handler',
    role: lambdaExecutionRole,
    securityGroup: lambdaSecurityGroup,
    vpc: DefaultVpc,
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
    timeout: Duration.minutes(2),
});
```

Comment: you are hardcoding vpc id which is not what the question asks!