# AWS CDK Could not find any VPCs matching

Tags: typescript, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk

I am trying to import and existing non-default VPC into my CDK app. I have seen a lot of questions asked regrading the VPC fromLookup and not much of solution. I am having issues where the function vpc.fromLookup returns "Could not find any VPCs matching".
I have provided these filters, and the env. account and region are set as well in the stack. I just cant figure out why the VPC is not found. I have triple checked the VPC id and Name and it all exists. any help is truly appreciated as I am new to AWS and CDK.

I have also trying just using tagName or VPCId but still got the same error.

> [Error at /MyStack] Could not find any VPCs matching
> {"account":"00000000","region":"ca-central-1","filter":{"tag:aws-cdk:subnet-type":"private","vpc-id":"vpc-00000000","tag:Name":"vpc","isDefault":"false"},"returnAsymmetricSubnets":true}
> Found errors

```
const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, "VPC", {  vpcName: vpcName,  isDefault: false,
       vpcId: vpcId, tags: { "aws-cdk:subnet-type": "private" }, 
});

env: {
 account: process.env.CDK_DEPLOY_ACCOUNT || process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT,
 region: process.env.CDK_DEPLOY_REGION || process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION, 
},
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import existing VPC in aws cdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59301265/how-to-import-existing-vpc-in-aws-cdk)

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved.
My issue was that the BastionHostLinux was set as subnetType Public and thats why I was getting error "There are no '${subnetType}' subnet groups in this VPC". which led me to think that I need to add tags to my VPC. sure enough adding the tags filter to my VPC resolved the error but then I was getting the " Could not find any VPCs matching...". So I learned – don’t rely on ERROR Messages...

Changed VPC

```
const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, "VPC", {  vpcName: vpcName,  isDefault: false,
   vpcId: vpcId, tags: { "aws-cdk:subnet-type": "private" }, },
```

to

```
const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, "VPC", {
  vpcId: vpcId,
  isDefault: false,
});
```

and VPC is imported no problem.